# Choosing indexes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Let's imagine we have the following table

```
 TABLE Something
      id
      description
      status

      PK (clustered index): id
      NC Index: id_status
```

1. Is having the NC index useless?
2. If we replace NC index id_status with index status, and the query references status and id in the JOIN query, does this mean PK_id and PK_status will be both used?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not.  Generally an index is more interesting to a query than a table.  How are you intending to use the table.

Comment: I've just been reviewing existing indexes and came across that. If I can locate which procedure is using it, I can fiddle around around with the index and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, just help to find all Stored Procedures that have dependency on specific table. This way you can check how your indexes are used or not used by SP

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(sed.referencing_id) AS 'ReferEntity'
   ,o.type_desc AS 'Description'
   ,UPPER(sed.referenced_database_name) AS 'DB_Name'
   ,sed.referenced_schema_name AS 'Schema'
   ,sed.referenced_entity_name as 'EntityName'
   ,count(*) over (partition by OBJECT_NAME(sed.referencing_id)) as CountAll
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS sed 
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o
    ON sed.referencing_id = o.object_id
WHERE o.type_desc = 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE'
    and sed.referenced_entity_name = 'MyTable'
order by 1
```

Comment: This is actually good advice here because who knows what is using this index. Maybe it is used only once a day, but for an important query.